# function onblur is not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was trying to call a javascript function onblur of a field.

the two issues that I was facing were

1) on page load the popup ( that is in the function call) is getting called automatically.

2) I am getting uncaught reference error in console when I am trying to access the function onblur.

following is the code that I am using:

HTML :

```
<div class="contact section s4">
            <div class="container">
                <h4>Think and Ink</h4>
                <p class="contact-head">Note: No identity of ur's will be stored or revealed to anybody. feel safe and keep posting what's there in ur heart</p>
                <div class="row contact-form">
                    <form>
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-box">
                            <input data-ng-model="toName" type="text" placeholder="To: Full Name" onblur="myFunction()"/>
                            <input required data-ng-model="song" type="text" placeholder="Any song dedication for this person.?" />
                            <input required data-ng-model="liking" type="text" placeholder="What you like about him/her.?" />
                        <!--    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" /> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 textarea">
                            <textarea required data-ng-model="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div><br />
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-red-lg" data-ng-click="submit()" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                </div>


                <!----start-copy-right---->

                <!----//End-copy-right---->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dialogBackdrop" ng-show='customError'>
        <div class="dialog">
            <div>
                <div class="dialogHead">Sorry</div>
                <div class="dialogContent">{{customErrorDialogContent}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class='dialogBtnHolder'>
                <div class="dialogBtn" ng-click='errorDialogCancel()'> OK</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);




app.controller("MyAppController",function ($scope,$rootScope,$http,$window)
        {
        alert ("form");


        $scope.myFunction = function (){
            if ($scope.toName==null)
                {
                var nullError = "Name cannot be Null.Please Retry..";
                 $scope.customErrorDialogContent= nullError;
                 $scope.customError= true;
                }


        };

        $scope.errorDialogCancel = function(){
            $scope.customError = false;
        };

  $scope.submit = function () {
                alert("clicked");

                if ($scope.toName==null || $scope.toName=="")
                    {
                    console.log("empty");
                    }
                $window.location.href='http://10.17.60.197:8080/spring_test/home.html';
                 $http.post('rest/postmessage',{toName:$scope.toName, song:$scope.song, liking: $scope.liking, msg: $scope.msg})
                 .success(function(data)
                     {
                     $scope.optyCmtDtls = data;



                     }).error(function(data){});

           };




        });
```

**not complete code ( but explains the problem)

Can anyone help me with the same. ??

Comment: use ng-blur in place of onblur..

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-blur` and not `onblur`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

If you use `onblur` your function must be global and not be defined inside your scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here I just removed onblur with ng-blur.. Now it will work

```
<input data-ng-model="toName" type="text" placeholder="To: Full Name" ng-blur="myFunction()"/>
```